# Button On and OFF Click Events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `addClass` and `removeClass` so that I can process further with compare charts.

Code:

```
$('li').click(function (evt) {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "Btn1"){
     $(this).addClass("selected");
     chart($(this).attr("class"));
     alert($(this).attr("class")); alert output -->Btn1
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the user again clicks on the button - setting it to the off state - the chart does not go off.

Can you please provide a reference for this?

Comment: Where's the else part or toggle class you need to write code for click on off button also

Comment: I literally don't understand a thing ... Could you put some effort in your question and illustrate the issue a bit more clear ? Can you give us your scenario ? I mean what does `chart()` do ? Are we supposed to guess ?

Comment: `i mean to off the chart does not goes off`. Not sure what that means

Comment: Basically, on button click i am displaying a chart and when the same button gets click the chart should not get display. (test == true ? $(".Btn1").show() : $(".Btn1").hide());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
if ($(this).attr("class") == "Btn1 selected"){
   $(this).removeClass("selected");
   alert($(this).attr("class")); //alert output -->Btn1
}else if($(this).attr("class") == "Btn1"){
     $(this).addClass("selected");
     alert($(this).attr("class")); //alert output -->Btn1 selected
}
```

Comment: Thanks imbondbaby and Silz.... Both the codes have gave the clear idea about to goes with this requirement. thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the point of `chart()` but...

Try this:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "Btn1") {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    } else {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqauL/1)**